# T-SQL: How to find matching records without a cursor

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have two tables: ItemCriteria and Item

ItemCriteria has the following fields

```
ID
Criteria1
Criteria2
Criteria3
Criteria4
Criteria5
```

Item has the same fields excluding the ID field

I need to find all items in the Item table that have 1 or more matching Criteria fields (excluding NULLS), and return the number of matches.

So, for example, if I have records in ItemCriteria that looks as follows:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | Criteria1 | Criteria2 | Criteria3 | Criteria4 | Criteria5 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | NULL      | AAB       | AAC       | NULL      | NULL      |
|  2 | AAB       | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
|  3 | NULL      | AAC       | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
|  4 | AAA       | NULL      | AAC       | NULL      | NULL      |
|  5 | BBB       | AAB       | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

And I have the following rows in Item

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Criteria1 | Criteria2 | Criteria3 | Criteria4 | Criteria5 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| AAA       | AAB       | AAC       | NULL      | NULL      |
| AAB       | AAC       | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I would expect the results to be:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------------+----------------+
| Criteria1 | Criteria2 | Criteria3 | Criteria4 | Criteria5 | MatchingCriteria | ItemCriteriaID |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------------+----------------+
| AAA       | AAB       | AAC       | NULL      | NULL      |                2 |              1 |
| AAB       | AAC       | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |                1 |              2 |
| AAB       | AAC       | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |                1 |              3 |
| AAA       | AAB       | AAC       | NULL      | NULL      |                2 |              4 |
| AAA       | AAB       | AAC       | NULL      | NULL      |                1 |              5 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------------+----------------+
```

At the moment I have a stored procedure that opens a cursor on ItemCriteria and steps through the entries, and then for each entry
creates a dynamic SQL statement that is executed. The results of the query are inserted into a Temporary table. Once complete, the 
values in the temporary tables are processed and the results returned to the caller.

This is very slow when large number of records are involved. Is there a better / faster way of doing this?

Comment: Can there ever be more than one matching criteria? If so do you just want the first?

Comment: Yes, there can be more than one matching criteria. If 3 matched, then the MatchingCriteria should return 3.

Comment: Can you confirm the 3rd row of your expected results? How is MatchingCriteria 1? Should it not be 2?

Comment: No, record 3 in ItemCriteria only has 1 match. (Criteria2 field AAC)

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the requirements correctly then it's pretty straightforward. You can use multiple ORed conditions in the join. As you've mentioned that there may be multiple matches I've used SELECT TOP 1 inside CROSS APPLY to ensure we only get 1 match - if this doesn't give you the match you need then you could add an ORDER BY to the subselect.

```
declare @ItemCriteria table (id int, criteria1 char(3), criteria2 char(3), criteria3 char(3), criteria4 char(3), criteria5 char(3))
declare @Item table (criteria1 char(3), criteria2 char(3), criteria3 char(3), criteria4 char(3), criteria5 char(3))

insert @ItemCriteria values 
    (1 , NULL, 'AAB', 'AAC', NULL, NULL),
    (2 ,'AAB', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (3 , NULL, 'AAC', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (4 ,'AAA', NULL, 'AAC', NULL, NULL),
    (5 ,'BBB', 'AAB', NULL, NULL, NULL)

insert @item values 
    ('AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', NULL, NULL),
    ('AAB', 'AAC', NULL, NULL, NULL)

select
    coalesce(i.criteria1, ic.criteria1) as Criteria1,
    coalesce(i.criteria2, ic.criteria2) as Criteria2,
    coalesce(i.criteria3, ic.criteria3) as Criteria3,
    coalesce(i.criteria4, ic.criteria4) as Criteria4,
    coalesce(i.criteria5, ic.criteria5) as Criteria5,
    case when i.criteria1 = ic.criteria1 then 1 else 0 end +
        case when i.criteria2 = ic.criteria2 then 1 else 0 end +
        case when i.criteria3 = ic.criteria3 then 1 else 0 end +
        case when i.criteria4 = ic.criteria4 then 1 else 0 end +
        case when i.criteria5 = ic.criteria5 then 1  else 0 end as MatchingCriteria,
    ic.id as ItemCriteriaID
from
    @ItemCriteria ic
        left join @Item i on i.criteria1 = ic.criteria1 
                          or i.criteria2 = ic.criteria2 
                          or i.criteria3 = ic.criteria3 
                          or i.criteria4 = ic.criteria4 
                          or i.criteria5 = ic.criteria5
```

Comment: There could be multiple records in Item that match a single ItemCriteria record, so not sure the top 1 in the CROSS APPLY would give me the results I need. Also, the MatchingCriteria is not the position of the matching item, but a Count of Matches. So, the MatchingCriteria of ItemCriteriaID 3 should actually be 1 (my fault for hasty reply before)

Answer (score 0):

Here try this out:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ItemCriteria') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ItemCriteria
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Item') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Item

CREATE TABLE #ItemCriteria
(
    ID INT,
    Criteria1 VARCHAR(5),
    Criteria2 VARCHAR(5),
    Criteria3 VARCHAR(5),
    Criteria4 VARCHAR(5),
    Criteria5 VARCHAR(5),
)

INSERT INTO #ItemCriteria
VALUES  (1,NULL,'AAB','AAC',NULL,NULL),
        (2,'AAB',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
        (3,NULL,'AAC',NULL,NULL,NULL),
        (4,'AAA',NULL,'AAC',NULL,NULL),
        (5,'BBB','AAB',NULL,NULL,NULL);

CREATE TABLE #Item
(
    Criteria1 VARCHAR(5),
    Criteria2 VARCHAR(5),
    Criteria3 VARCHAR(5),
    Criteria4 VARCHAR(5),
    Criteria5 VARCHAR(5),
);

INSERT INTO #Item
VALUES  ('AAA','AAB','AAC',NULL,NULL),
        ('AAB','AAC',NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Okay now that I have set up the tables, here's for the criteria matching.

```
 SELECT A.*,
        CASE WHEN A.Criteria1 = B.Criteria1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN A.Criteria2 = B.Criteria2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN A.Criteria3 = B.Criteria3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN A.Criteria4 = B.Criteria4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN A.Criteria5 = B.Criteria5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        AS MatchingCriteria,
        B.ID AS ItemCriteriaID
FROM #Item A
INNER JOIN #ItemCriteria B
ON  A.Criteria1 = B.Criteria1
    OR A.Criteria2 = B.Criteria2
    OR A.Criteria3 = B.Criteria3
    OR A.Criteria4 = B.Criteria4
    OR A.Criteria5 = B.Criteria5
ORDER BY B.ID
```

Results:

```
Criteria1 Criteria2 Criteria3 Criteria4 Criteria5 MatchingCriteria ItemCriteriaID
--------- --------- --------- --------- --------- ---------------- --------------
AAA       AAB       AAC       NULL      NULL      2                1
AAB       AAC       NULL      NULL      NULL      1                2
AAB       AAC       NULL      NULL      NULL      1                3
AAA       AAB       AAC       NULL      NULL      2                4
AAA       AAB       AAC       NULL      NULL      1                5
```